# Blur everything except one div

Tags: jquery, html

How can I blur everything with javascript click except one element `.personalPhoto` and toggle it, I tried this but not working

```
    function photoCheck(){
        $('.personalPhoto').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('aaasssddd');
            if($(this).hasClass('aaasssddd')){
                $(this).css({'transform':'scale(2.5)'});
                $(window > this).css({'filter':'blur(2px)'});
            } else {
                 $(this).css({'transform':'scale(1)'});
            }
        })
    }
    photoCheck();
```

```html
<div class="personalPhoto"><img src="images/camera.png"></div>
```

Comment: *"blur everything"*? Define the meaning of "blur everything". Like the entire website?

Answer (score 1):

You're only toggling the blur of the one photo, not all the other photos.   So you would want something like this:

```
function photoCheck(){
    $('.personalPhoto').click(function(){
        // blur all the photos
        $('.personalPhoto').each(function() {
            $(this).css({'transform':'scale(2.5)'});
            $(window > this).css({'filter':'blur(2px)'});
        });
        // then unblur the clicked photo
        $(this).css({'transform':'scale(1)'});
        $(window > this).css({'filter':'blur(0)'});
    })
}
photoCheck();
```

Comment: `window > this` window is greater than what?

Comment: Also why the use of `each` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could select all the elements with class `.personalPhoto` *except* `this` one, and blur them:

```
function photoCheck(){
    $('.personalPhoto').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('aaasssddd');
        $('.personalPhoto').not($(this)).css({'filter':'blur(2px)'});
    });
}
photoCheck();
```

Comment: Yep, using the .not is a nice efficient way to go about it!